# Is it possible to run an Eclipse builder on workbench startup?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a builder as an Eclipse plugin, which creates markers in XML documents.

Unfortunately the builder only runs when I edit and save the document.

Is it possible to run the builder when the workbench launches? Or even better, can you make sure the builder is always aware of the state of the XML document?

Comment: Markers can be persistent - once they are created they stay until they are explicitly deleted even if you exit and restart Eclipse.